# Log Out User and Change token to NIL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, session, authentication

I've started to create an Api for my rails application. I am currently creating the Sessions Controller for Log in.

Sign Out seems to be working, but I'd really like the to be able to Sign Out the User AND set the users oauth_token equal to NIL.(oauth_token = nil)

I've tried the code below, but it can't seem to find the correct user by using their oauth_token.

Curl Command

```
 curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE 
http://localhost:3000/api/sessions/\?auth_token\=5c147a84cd5418771b9063dddcbfde96d5a8630b
```

**API CONTROLLER**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                       :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

      respond_to :json

      def destroy 
        user = User.find_by_oauth_token(params[:session][:oauth_token])
        if user.present?
          user.oauth_token = nil
          user.save
        end
        sign_out
        render :status => 200,
         :json => { :success => true,
                    :info => "Logged Out",
                    :data => {} }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**SESSION HELPER**

```
def sign_out 
  current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
### API Routes
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

**LOGS**

```
Started DELETE "/api/sessions/?auth_token=5c147a84cd5418771b9063dddcbfde96d5a8630b" 
for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-01 00:05:37 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::SessionsController#destroy as JSON
  Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"5c147a84cd5418771b9063dddcbfde96d5a8630b", "session"=>{}}
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."oauth_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 130ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by changing my Curl Command to this:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE
http://localhost:3000/api/sessions -d 
"{\"session\":{\"oauth_token\":\"5c147a84cd5418771b9063dddcbfde96d5a8630b\"}}"
```